# beautiful-jekyll theme: How to modify the page title color in CSS?

Tags: html, css, jekyll, jekyll-theme

I have set up a "beautiful Jekyll" blog/GitHub page and I would like to change the font color of the page title and subtitle.

I would like to change the text color:

```
Beautiful Jekyll
Build a beautiful and simple website in minutes
```

I cannot find the right place in the `main.css`. I have looked into the `index.html`, the `config.yml`, and the `css` folder but cannot find where to change the color.

Around line 24ish to line 35ish of the `main.css` file I have:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
}

a {
  color: {{ site.link-col }};
}

.header_class {
  color: red;
}
```

On line 28 of the `index.html` file I have:

```
<h1 class="header_class">{% if page.title %}{{ page.title }}{% else %}<br/>{% endif %}</h1>
```

Current website: https://deanattali.com/beautiful-jekyll/
GitHub page: https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `<h1>` for `page.title` in the [header.html](https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll/blob/96c25086b57e6af1fd44eec8f0bcdadce33730a7/_includes/header.html).

**Problem:** The parent div has a class `<div class="{{ include.type }}-heading">` but the element itself has no class or id which could be used in the CSS.

**Solution:** You need to add another class to the HTML and define new styles in the CSS to get only the colored `page.title`.

In case you only define the color on the existing `<h1>`in your CSS, each document's title would be colored, as the CSS defines the same styles for `<h1>` to `<h6>`.

Check out this tutorial on [how to use classes in HTML/CSS](https://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/getting-to-know-css/#combining-selectors).

#### Testing HTML and CSS changes

Use the inspector (dev tools) in your browser (press F12) to see the elements of a page. You can even test what happens when you add or change specific CSS attributes. Learn what I mean and [how to do it on your own](https://designtlc.com/use-chrome-inspector-edit-website-css/).

For testing, I have added `color: red` to the `<h1>` tag:

[image: inspector / dev tools]

#### Add a class to your HTML and update your CSS

1. Go to line 28 in the [header.html](https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll/blob/ff32d628f4aea4c21f333d62ba1c701649e1722e/_includes/header.html#L28)  and add change `<h1>` to  `<h1 class="your-test-class">`
2. Go to the [main.css](https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll/blob/ff32d628f4aea4c21f333d62ba1c701649e1722e/css/main.css#L24) and add the following below the `<h1,...>`definition:

```
.your-test-class {
  color: red;
}
```

Note: This h1 tag example would also work for the sub-title.

Comment: Awesome thanks! can you send me the code to change the `<h1>` to red? I understand more or less whats going on with css but not an expert. How can I add another class to the html file and define the css class?

Comment: you mean below the `h1, h2, h3l, h4 h5. h6` part of the `main.css`?  `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6`? I have the following: `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  .my-header-class {
  color: red;
}
  
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
}
a {
  color: {{ site.link-col }};
}`

Comment: .my-header-class is a separate block, you have h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 { font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 800; } a { color: {{ site.link-col }}; } and  .my-header-class { color: red; }

Comment: I added an edit of the changes I made, the color has not changed.

Comment: EDIT: Yes the colors did change! I just needed to wait until the website updated! Thanks again!